# Setting up vhost for various web applications on AWS

Tags: angularjs, apache, amazon-web-services, vhosts

On my AWS instance, I have the following setup

```
/var/www/html/admin <--- angularjs application
/var/www/html/api <--- angularjs application
/var/www/html/main <--- django application
```

How do I make them all accessible as "individual sites"? For example, browsing to:

```
http://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/admin
http://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/api
http://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/main
```

Should each be like going to a self contained site.

Right now going to `http://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/main` for instance (which is an AngularJS application), I see errors like this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I logged onto the site and noticed that it thinks the assets live a directory above as opposed to in the "main" subdirectory. I can understand that I need to set up vhosts somehow... where do these go on an AWS instance and would they look like this?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@main.com
    ServerName main.com
    ServerAlias www.main.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/main

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@main.com
    ServerName main.com/api
    ServerAlias www.main.com/api
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/api

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@main.com
    ServerName main.com/admin
    ServerAlias www.main.com/admin
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/admin

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: if you are not going to use individual domain names, why shouldn't just one virtual host with `ServerName ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
` `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` work?

Comment: Can you please show me an example of how it would look like? I would still like to retain the directory structure I have right now, with main being the entry point for the site and everything else being a “sub domain”

Comment: try just one VirtualHost with two lines. If it works, all the other you can add afterwards.